# Open Application with launch activity null

Tags: android

I need to launch activities such as camera from my application.I am unable to use intents to do this as it crashes every time.I am able to open any other application such as calculator etc(those whose launch activities are not null).
I have added a permission in my android manifest so this is not the problem.In the log cat it says ActivityNotfoundexception when i try to open the camera.Is there any other way to open the camera using an intent.

Comment: Show us the code you are using, and what Line the logcat says the error is on

Comment: Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(s[i]);s[i] stores the packeage name of the camera and i start the activity using startActivity(mIntent)

Comment: We need more than that, what is i, what null checks do you do. What does the logcat show. Please click *edit* on your question and append the code in there.

Comment: i is an Integer which holds the position of the package name i want to open.s[i] = packageInfo.packageName;It is to be noted that the above code works for opening a calculator,clock,settings etc.But it throws a null pointer exception when i try to open the camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity not found exception sounds like the manifest are you sure it's in the manifest and that your class is extending Activity? It's harder to give a more specific answer without seeing some code.

Comment: 05-27 21:27:45.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 21:27:45.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2472): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 21:27:45.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2472):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
05-27 21:27:45.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2472):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
05-27 21:27:45.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2472):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
05-27 21:27:45.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2472):     at

Comment: Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(s[i]);s[i] stores the packeage name of the camera and i start the activity using startActivity(mIntent).i is an Integer which holds the position of the package name i want to open.s[i] = packageInfo.packageName;It is to be noted that the above code works for opening a calculator,clock,settings etc.But it throws a null pointer exception when i try to open the camera

Answer (score 0):

you should define your each activity you've created , in your **manifest** like this :

```
<activity android:name="MyNewActivity" ></activity>
```